# Sort array values base from the number of segments

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of URLS

Eg:

```
['support/maintenance', 'support/', 'support/faq/laminator']
```

How do I sort it base from the number of segments?

Expected result:

```
['support/faq/maninator', 'support/maintenance, 'support/']
```

Comment: have you tries anything.

Comment: There are already 8 answers here, but if you want a Laravel one line solution, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you've already chosen the answer and there are 8 another answers, but still, I'll give you more elegant Laravel solution (since you're using the framework). Use the [`sortByDesc()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortbydesc) collection method:

```
collect($array)->sortByDesc(function($i) { return count(explode('/', $i)); });
```

One readable line.

You can iterate over result as you would iterate over a usual array. But if you need an array for some reason, add `->toArray()` at the end.

If you want to remove `/` from the beginning and the end of each string when counting segments, add `trim($i, '/')` into the closure like this `explode('/', trim($i, '/'))`

Comment: @Kerwin if you'll use this solution in the real app, please choose this answer as the best one.

Answer (score 6):

Use **[arsort](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)** to organize in reverse order, then use **[usort](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)** to sort by string size.

```
<?php

$arr = ['support/maintenance', 'support/', 'support/faq/laminator'];

function sortOrder($currentValue, $nextValue) {
    $totalSegmentsOfTheCurrentIndex = count(preg_split('/\//', $currentValue, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
    $totalSegmentsOfTheNextIndex  = count(preg_split('/\//', $nextValue, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

    // The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
    return $totalSegmentsOfTheNextIndex - $totalSegmentsOfTheCurrentIndex;
}

usort($arr, 'sortOrder');

var_export($arr);
```

Comment: i think you are just comparing the length of the url not the segments, it may fail if their comes a long url segment

Comment: I like the code of @Adam Szmyd because it little bit simpler than yours but your sorting works well than Adam so thank you! Answer selected.

Answer (score 3):

You should use usort with custom comparator to count the number of segments after exploding each element by the divider (which is an `/` in this case):

```
function comparator($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return count(explode('/', $a)) < count(explode('/', $b)) ? 1 : -1;
}

$array = ['support/maintenance', 'support/', 'support/faq/laminator'];

usort($array, "comparator");

print_r($array);
/**
Array
(
    [0] => support/faq/laminator
    [1] => support/maintenance
    [2] => support/
)
*/
```

Comment: I like your code because its simple but when I test it, it gives wrong sorting order. Still thank you +1

Comment: Whats wrong with the order? Its the same as you wanted it to be in your first post (`['support/faq/maninator', 'support/maintenance, 'support/']`)

Answer (score 2):

you can get each url segments count using this function and sort according to this

```
    function count_segment($str) {
        $path = trim($str, '/');
        return count(explode('/', $path));      
    }

   function arrange($a, $b) {
      if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
       }
       return count_segment($b)-count_segment($a);
   }  

usort($arr, 'arrange');
```

try sorting the values in the array using this count of segments

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php 
$ar = ['support/maintenance', 'support/', 'support/faq/laminator'];
for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($ar);$i++)
{ 
    for($j=$i+1;$j<sizeof($ar);$j++) {

        if(sizeof(explode("/",rtrim($ar[$i],"/")))<sizeof(explode("/",rtrim($ar[$j],"/"))))
        {
            $temp = $ar[$i];
            $ar[$i]= $ar[$j];
            $ar[$j]=$temp;
        }
    }
}
print_r($ar);
```

Comment: Answer is Array ( [0] => support/faq/laminator [1] => support/maintenance [2] => support/ )

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<?php
    $array = array('support/maintenance', 'support/', 'support/faq/laminator');
    $new = array();
    foreach($array as $r){
        $key = explode('/',$r);//convert the element into array by '/' occurence.
        $key = count(array_filter($key));//remove the empty elements of $key array and count elements.
        $new[$key][] = $r; //assign that row to $new[$key] array. This is because of '/' same occurrence.
    }
    krsort($new); sort $new array by key in descending order
    $final = array_merge(...$new); merge $new array. $final array has your result.
    echo '<pre>';print_r($final);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially split each element on '/' then sort the array by the length of sub-arrays then join the sub-arrays on '/'. I am not extremely familiar with php syntax but something like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    arr[i].split('/')
}
// possibly bubble sort depending on length of array by highest length
// same loop with a join instead of a split
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$urlArray = array('support/maintenance', 'support/', 'support/faq/laminator');

foreach ($urlArray as $val){

    $countExploded[] = count(array_filter(explode('/', $val)));

}

asort($countExploded);
$sortedUrlArray = array_replace($countExploded, $urlArray);

print_r($sortedUrlArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this we need to remove the `/` to avoid gettting a wrong value.

**Example**

```
var_dump(explode('/', 'support/'));
```

**Result:** `array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "support" [1]=> string(0) "" }`

As you can see it returns **2**! which is wrong.

**Solution:**

To fix this we need to trim the string first. Instead of using `count()`, `explode` and `trim`. We will only use `substring_count()` and `trim()`.

**Here is the whole code:**

```
function sort_url($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {return 0;}
    return substr_count(trim($a,'/'),'/') > substr_count(trim($b,'/'),'/') ? -1 : 1;
}
$array = ['support/maintenance', 'support/', 'support/faq/laminator'];
usort($array, "sort_url");
print_r($array);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => support/faq/laminator [1] => support/maintenance [2] => support/ )
```